# Multiple windows in one page c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to do a page which is similar to this http://www.manuliferetirement.sg/calculator.html on c# asp.net page. Is it possible to put multiple smaller pages/section and allow me to click next to go to the next section with c# asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Why yes! Inspecting the HTML code of the website, they merely had all the steps laid out in their own respective `divs`, and simply changed the CSS styling of each div from `display: none` to `display: block` to show them, and the opposite to hide them. Try right-clicking the webpage and selecting "Inspect Element", then try going through the steps. It should make everything clear.

If you want to do this, you'd need a bit of javascript knowledge, but it is very doable on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you know jQuery, It will help you a lot. Simply make your pages as `div` inside a single page and give them an unique `ID`.

```
    <div class="page">
        <div id="Page_One">
            <input type="text" name="email_address" placeholder="Email Address"/>
            <button id="GoToSecond">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Page_Two" class="hidden">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            <input type="password" name="retype_password" placeholder="Retype Password"/>
            <button id="GoToLast">Next</button>
            <button id="ReturnToFirst">Back</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Page_Three" class="hidden">
            <p>A confirmation code has been sent to your email. Put your code here</p>
            <input type="text" name="confirmation_code" placeholder="Code"/>
            <button id="AddUser">Add User</button>
            <button id="ReturnToSecond">Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Inside here you need to do some javascript to handle your ui transition
            $("#GoToSecond").on('click', function(e){
                //Do your validation to move next
                $('#Page_One').hide("slide", {direction: "left"});
                $('#Page_Two').delay(500).show("slide", {direction: "right"});
            });

            //Second Page functions
            $("#ReturnToFirst").on('click', function(e){
                $('#Page_Two').hide("slide", {direction: "right"});
                $('#Page_One').delay(600).show("slide", {direction: "left"});
            });

            $("#GoToLast").on('click', function(e){
                //Do your validation to move next
                $('#Page_Two').hide("slide", {direction: "left"});
                $('#Page_Three').delay(600).show("slide", {direction: "right"});
            });

            //Last Page functions
            $("#ReturnToSecond").on('click', function(e){
                $('#Page_Three').hide("slide", {direction: "right"});
                $('#Page_Two').delay(600).show("slide", {direction: "left"});
            });

            $("#AddUser").on('click', function(e){
                alert("Make your submission here");
            });

        })
    </script>

    <style>
        .page{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 300px;
            min-height: 200px;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
        .hidden{ display: none;}
    </style>
```